# Understanding Riemannian metrics at points on a manifold that have the 'same' tangent plane

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

This question came up when I was working through Do Carmo; specifically after the introduction of Riemannian Manifolds and isometries between them.

Take $S^n$ and the antipodal map $A$, for example. To show that $A$ is an isometry, one must show that for all $p$ in $S^n$, the following holds:

$$
<dA_p (u),dA_p(v)>_{-p} = <u,v>_{p}
$$

It is clear that the left hand side is just $<u,v>_{-p}$. So the remainder of the proof is showing that the two inner products are the same on antipodal points of the sphere. Visually, this makes sense as if you imagine the tangent planes at antipodal points of $S^2$ as linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$, they define the same hyperplane. Does it follow that the inner products on these plane given a Riemannian metric must be the same?

The definition of a Riemannian metric I am using here is just a map $<,>_q:T_qS^n\times T_qS^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that there is a notion of local differentiability while varying $q$.

Is there a general idea that tangent spaces that lead to the same hyperplanes when considering the manifold as some embedding in Euclidean space lead to the same inner products on these tangent spaces?

Comment: I don't know a general answer to your question but the fact that the antipodal map is an isometry can be seen directly since it is a composition of $n+1$ reflection with respect to hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$..maybe this can help visualizing your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Riemannian metric you are using here is the restriction of the usual scalar product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, that is
$$\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_p=\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle|_{T_pS\times T_pS},$$
then as soon as $T_pS=T_qS$, you will have $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_p=\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_q$. This is indeed the case here since $T_pS=p^\perp=(-p)^\perp=T_{-p}S$. If the Riemannian metric depends of the point, then it can no longer be true.

Comment: I guess I would've thought of the tangent space at a point as being a 'formal' module over the partial derivatives at that point, so I wouldn't have considered the idea of those two tangent spaces being equal in any interesting sense. I do see what you mean geometrically though

Comment: Yes, it is something you can only do when the ambient manifold is an Euclidean space $E$: for these you have canonical isomorphisms $E\simeq T_pE, v\mapsto\partial_v$, and if you have a submanifold $S\subset E$ of an Euclidean space you can identify its tangent space with a subspace of $E$ with  $T_pS\simeq i_*(T_pS)\subset T_pE\simeq E$, where $i:S\to E$ is the inclusion and $i_*$ its differential.